# How to structure three.js project (with client side rendering requirements) in next.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, next.js, use-effect, react-three-fiber

### Goal

To get [this](https://codepen.io/HunorMarton/pen/MWjBRWp) mini-game working in next.js powered environment 'the right way'.

---

### Background

The linked game uses [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) which in turn requires the window object to update certain variables according to the game logic.
And next.js does not have a window object defined on the server side, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app).
So, to tackle this problem, I moved the window object inside of useEffect hook provided by react as mentioned in [this](https://dev.to/vvo/how-to-solve-window-is-not-defined-errors-in-react-and-next-js-5f97) article.

---

### Problem

Moving window inside of useEffect worked but other helper variables depends on its value, so to make it all work without errors, I had to move the entire javascript code with some minor adjustments inside of useEffect of a component page that I created.

---

### Extra

I started this project by trying to recreate this game using [react-three-fiber](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction) as it abstracts well with Next.js but I had to change my ways because the documentation was not clear and lacks example code.
**To even change the default camera setting from perspective to orthographic inside of Canvas tag was a little unruly.**
But as explained by [Bruno Simon](https://bruno-simon.com/), [Paul Henschel](https://twitter.com/0xca0a?lang=en) and others, three becomes quite hard to manage/scale/change/reuse when the code becomes complex.
And I wish to maintain the component property of my code.

How shall I go about it?
Thankyou for any leads, references to courses, articles.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452019/how-to-organize-imports-in-a-react-app-with-three-js-without-using-the-window-o) stackoverflow thread poses a similar question to mine but I have my what ifs.

---

### Code

```js
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { React, useState, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import * as CANNON from 'cannon'

export default function Home() {

  useEffect(() => {

window.focus(); // Capture keys right away (by default focus is on editor)

let camera, scene, renderer; // ThreeJS globals
let world; // CannonJs world
let lastTime; // Last timestamp of animation
let stack; // Parts that stay solid on top of each other
let overhangs; // Overhanging parts that fall down
const boxHeight = 1; // Height of each layer
const originalBoxSize = 3; // Original width and height of a box
let autopilot;
let gameEnded;
let robotPrecision; // Determines how precise the game is on autopilot

const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
const instructionsElement = document.getElementById("instructions");
const resultsElement = document.getElementById("results");

init();

// Determines how precise the game is on autopilot
function setRobotPrecision() {
  robotPrecision = Math.random() * 1 - 0.5;
}

function init() {
  autopilot = true;
  gameEnded = false;
  lastTime = 0;
  stack = [];
  overhangs = [];
  setRobotPrecision();

  // Initialize CannonJS
  world = new CANNON.World();
  world.gravity.set(0, -10, 0); // Gravity pulls things down
  world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();
  world.solver.iterations = 40;

  // Initialize ThreeJs
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const width = 10;
  const height = width / aspect;

  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    width / -2, // left
    width / 2, // right
    height / 2, // top
    height / -2, // bottom
    0, // near plane
    100 // far plane
  );

  /*
  // If you want to use perspective camera instead, uncomment these lines
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45, // field of view
    aspect, // aspect ratio
    1, // near plane
    100 // far plane
  );
  */

  camera.position.set(4, 4, 4);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Foundation
  addLayer(0, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize);

  // First layer
  addLayer(-10, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize, "x");

  // Set up lights
  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
  dirLight.position.set(10, 20, 0);
  scene.add(dirLight);

  // Set up renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(animation);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function startGame() {
  autopilot = false;
  gameEnded = false;
  lastTime = 0;
  stack = [];
  overhangs = [];

  if (instructionsElement) instructionsElement.style.display = "none";
  if (resultsElement) resultsElement.style.display = "none";
  if (scoreElement) scoreElement.innerText = 0;

  if (world) {
    // Remove every object from world
    while (world.bodies.length > 0) {
      world.remove(world.bodies[0]);
    }
  }

  if (scene) {
    // Remove every Mesh from the scene
    while (scene.children.find((c) => c.type == "Mesh")) {
      const mesh = scene.children.find((c) => c.type == "Mesh");
      scene.remove(mesh);
    }

    // Foundation
    addLayer(0, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize);

    // First layer
    addLayer(-10, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize, "x");
  }

  if (camera) {
    // Reset camera positions
    camera.position.set(4, 4, 4);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

function addLayer(x, z, width, depth, direction) {
  const y = boxHeight * stack.length; // Add the new box one layer higher
  const layer = generateBox(x, y, z, width, depth, false);
  layer.direction = direction;
  stack.push(layer);
}

function addOverhang(x, z, width, depth) {
  const y = boxHeight * (stack.length - 1); // Add the new box one the same layer
  const overhang = generateBox(x, y, z, width, depth, true);
  overhangs.push(overhang);
}

function generateBox(x, y, z, width, depth, falls) {
  // ThreeJS
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, boxHeight, depth);
  const color = new THREE.Color(`hsl(${30 + stack.length * 4}, 100%, 50%)`);
  const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color });
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
  scene.add(mesh);

  // CannonJS
  const shape = new CANNON.Box(
    new CANNON.Vec3(width / 2, boxHeight / 2, depth / 2)
  );
  let mass = falls ? 5 : 0; // If it shouldn't fall then setting the mass to zero will keep it stationary
  mass *= width / originalBoxSize; // Reduce mass proportionately by size
  mass *= depth / originalBoxSize; // Reduce mass proportionately by size
  const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass, shape });
  body.position.set(x, y, z);
  world.addBody(body);

  return {
    threejs: mesh,
    cannonjs: body,
    width,
    depth
  };
}

function cutBox(topLayer, overlap, size, delta) {
  const direction = topLayer.direction;
  const newWidth = direction == "x" ? overlap : topLayer.width;
  const newDepth = direction == "z" ? overlap : topLayer.depth;

  // Update metadata
  topLayer.width = newWidth;
  topLayer.depth = newDepth;

  // Update ThreeJS model
  topLayer.threejs.scale[direction] = overlap / size;
  topLayer.threejs.position[direction] -= delta / 2;

  // Update CannonJS model
  topLayer.cannonjs.position[direction] -= delta / 2;

  // Replace shape to a smaller one (in CannonJS you can't simply just scale a shape)
  const shape = new CANNON.Box(
    new CANNON.Vec3(newWidth / 2, boxHeight / 2, newDepth / 2)
  );
  topLayer.cannonjs.shapes = [];
  topLayer.cannonjs.addShape(shape);
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", eventHandler);
window.addEventListener("touchstart", eventHandler);
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key == " ") {
    event.preventDefault();
    eventHandler();
    return;
  }
  if (event.key == "R" || event.key == "r") {
    event.preventDefault();
    startGame();
    return;
  }
});

function eventHandler() {
  if (autopilot) startGame();
  else splitBlockAndAddNextOneIfOverlaps();
}

function splitBlockAndAddNextOneIfOverlaps() {
  if (gameEnded) return;

  const topLayer = stack[stack.length - 1];
  const previousLayer = stack[stack.length - 2];

  const direction = topLayer.direction;

  const size = direction == "x" ? topLayer.width : topLayer.depth;
  const delta =
    topLayer.threejs.position[direction] -
    previousLayer.threejs.position[direction];
  const overhangSize = Math.abs(delta);
  const overlap = size - overhangSize;

  if (overlap > 0) {
    cutBox(topLayer, overlap, size, delta);

    // Overhang
    const overhangShift = (overlap / 2 + overhangSize / 2) * Math.sign(delta);
    const overhangX =
      direction == "x"
        ? topLayer.threejs.position.x + overhangShift
        : topLayer.threejs.position.x;
    const overhangZ =
      direction == "z"
        ? topLayer.threejs.position.z + overhangShift
        : topLayer.threejs.position.z;
    const overhangWidth = direction == "x" ? overhangSize : topLayer.width;
    const overhangDepth = direction == "z" ? overhangSize : topLayer.depth;

    addOverhang(overhangX, overhangZ, overhangWidth, overhangDepth);

    // Next layer
    const nextX = direction == "x" ? topLayer.threejs.position.x : -10;
    const nextZ = direction == "z" ? topLayer.threejs.position.z : -10;
    const newWidth = topLayer.width; // New layer has the same size as the cut top layer
    const newDepth = topLayer.depth; // New layer has the same size as the cut top layer
    const nextDirection = direction == "x" ? "z" : "x";

    if (scoreElement) scoreElement.innerText = stack.length - 1;
    addLayer(nextX, nextZ, newWidth, newDepth, nextDirection);
  } else {
    missedTheSpot();
  }
}

function missedTheSpot() {
  const topLayer = stack[stack.length - 1];

  // Turn to top layer into an overhang and let it fall down
  addOverhang(
    topLayer.threejs.position.x,
    topLayer.threejs.position.z,
    topLayer.width,
    topLayer.depth
  );
  world.remove(topLayer.cannonjs);
  scene.remove(topLayer.threejs);

  gameEnded = true;
  if (resultsElement && !autopilot) resultsElement.style.display = "flex";
}

function animation(time) {
  if (lastTime) {
    const timePassed = time - lastTime;
    const speed = 0.008;

    const topLayer = stack[stack.length - 1];
    const previousLayer = stack[stack.length - 2];

    // The top level box should move if the game has not ended AND
    // it's either NOT in autopilot or it is in autopilot and the box did not yet reach the robot position
    const boxShouldMove =
      !gameEnded &&
      (!autopilot ||
        (autopilot &&
          topLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] <
            previousLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] +
              robotPrecision));

    if (boxShouldMove) {
      // Keep the position visible on UI and the position in the model in sync
      topLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] += speed * timePassed;
      topLayer.cannonjs.position[topLayer.direction] += speed * timePassed;

      // If the box went beyond the stack then show up the fail screen
      if (topLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] > 10) {
        missedTheSpot();
      }
    } else {
      // If it shouldn't move then is it because the autopilot reached the correct position?
      // Because if so then next level is coming
      if (autopilot) {
        splitBlockAndAddNextOneIfOverlaps();
        setRobotPrecision();
      }
    }

    // 4 is the initial camera height
    if (camera.position.y < boxHeight * (stack.length - 2) + 4) {
      camera.position.y += speed * timePassed;
    }

    updatePhysics(timePassed);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  lastTime = time;
}

function updatePhysics(timePassed) {
  world.step(timePassed / 1000); // Step the physics world

  // Copy coordinates from Cannon.js to Three.js
  overhangs.forEach((element) => {
    element.threejs.position.copy(element.cannonjs.position);
    element.threejs.quaternion.copy(element.cannonjs.quaternion);
  });
}

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  // Adjust camera
  console.log("resize", window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const width = 10;
  const height = width / aspect;

  camera.top = height / 2;
  camera.bottom = height / -2;

  // Reset renderer
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

  })

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.nav}>
        <h2>Ritik Jangir</h2>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Honestly just add a check `typeof window !== 'undefined'` before using the window object

Comment: Have you considered that maybe Next.js isn't the best option for your use case? What benefits does your project gain from Next.js if everything is client-side rendered?

Comment: @juliomalves
react-three-fiber uses the react ecosystem to render the scene which is faster than using three.js. Yes, the rendering is happening on the client-side but r3f is optimized and is fast. Have a look at, https://youtu.be/rzhCVvacvMo?t=2166, Paul Henschel demonstrates how and why rendering with react is faster.

Comment: I was questioning the use of Next.js specifically, not React.

Comment: @juliomalves I agree with your perspective. But my goal is to eventually integrate a 3d model inside of a webapp, (think of an e-commerce site with 3D product models that user can interact with)
So, excuse me, you are right, for this particular use case I dont need next.js but when I am done learning this. I can make use of fast refresh, image optimization, and other features provided by next.js
If my understanding is wrong somewhere, please do correct me.
Thankyou for your response senior.